# Google Analytics Event Tracking: __utm.gif never finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, fiddler

I have a requirement to track downloads of PDF files in my site.

I am using my own plugin to achieve this: https://github.com/rsleggett/Quick-Event-Tracking

However, underneath all it does is call the trackEvent function with the correct parameters. My problem is that when tracking the PDF download the event is fired but never finishes loading:

Here's my code:

```
    <a href="_images/printer-certificate.pdf" class="track-pdf" target="_blank">Track lots</a>
    <script>
        $('.track-pdf').gaTrackEvent({
            category: 'Download',
            action: 'PDF',
            labelAttribute: 'href',
            useEvent: true,
            event: 'click'
        });
    </script>
```

Here's what I see in the Network panel for firebug:

[image: Firebug network panel]

This request never completes and this doesn't seem to be recorded in Google Analytics.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

I have tried adding a delay before changing the document.location like this:

```
    <a href="_images/printer-certificate.pdf" class="track-pdf" target="_blank">Track lots</a>
    <script>
        $('.track-pdf').gaTrackEvent({
            category: 'Download',
            action: 'PDF',
            labelAttribute: 'href',
            useEvent: true,
            event: 'click',
            complete: function (elem, e) {
                setTimeout(function () { document.location = $(elem).attr('href') }, 100);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This seems to work - the request completes if I look at it in fiddler. However, this feels hacky and I don't really want my downloads to open in the same window (it breaks my requirements anyway).

Any ideas?

Comment: You could open the pdf in another window instead of setting doc.location (with window.open), but that doesn't answer your original question. I see no reason why that would occur. Do all browsers act the same way?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Actually this works in Chrome which is interesting. Window.open is blocked by popup blockers, I did try that as well. Will try in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to remove the node which contains __utm.gif